# How to get a local variable value from onItemClickListener to use it on another activity?

Tags: android

I have a listview populated from database and on onItemLongClick I have a context menu which I want to use it to edit and update the selected item of list. The problem is that I don' t know how to get the selected item' s values so to use them on another activity which has a form with edittexts. I want when the new activity starts, these string values to be on the apporopriate edittexts.
Here is the onItemLongClick code:

```
    **REMOVED AND ADDED CORRECT CODE BELOW**
```

With the cursor I get the selected item's values and store them on Strings nameOfSong and artistOfSong.
How can I achive when the activity starts to be filled the respective edittexts?

**==EDIT==**
I used SharedPreferences in this way which works:

OnItemLongClick of first activity:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View arg1,
                final int position, final long arg3) {
            //bind context menu to listview' s onIitemLongClick(touch and hold)
            // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
               Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);

               // Get the state's capital from this row in the database.

               registerForContextMenu(listView);
                openContextMenu(listView);
                String nameOfSong = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("songname"));
                String artistOfSong = 
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("artist"));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putString("key1", nameOfSong);
                editor.putString("key2", artistOfSong);
                editor.commit();
```

second activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.update_item);

    etEditSong = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEditSong);
    etEditArtist = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEditArtist);
    sEditDance = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sUpdDanceList);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    etEditSong.setText(prefs.getString("key1", null));
    etEditArtist.setText(prefs.getString("key2", null));

}
```

Now I'm getting the strings on second activity. Now need to find how to update the database row from above editTexts values.

Comment: depend on when u are starting Activity ? if u are starting Activity on onItemLongClick then use `Intent` or `Bundle` for sending values to Next Activity on ListView Item Click and if u are starting Activity on menu Click then use `SharedPreferences` for sharing data between Activities

Comment: Added the SharedPrefereces code on my post. Unfortunately I get NullPointer Exception and points to the line SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySharedPreferences.edit();

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting the next activity from that long click, you can use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(KEY1, nameOfSong);
intent.putExtra(KEY2, artistOfSong);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in the receiving activity

```
String nameOfSong = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY1);
String artistOfSong = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY2);
```

If you're starting the activity from somewhere else, you can create a global instance variable and set it in your onItemLongClick, then do the same process wherever you start your activity.

Comment: I used SharedPreferences and I've managed to get the strings, thanks. I' ll post the corrected code on my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `SharedPreferences` just get the data in he `onCreate()` method of the activity that is using it.

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
String song = myPrefs.getString("key1", null);
String artist = myPrefs.getString("key2", null);
```

Then just set the text for the textviews you want to display the info

```
TextView song1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.song);
song1.setText(song);
```

you could do that with edittext if you want but if you're just displaying the title idk why you'd make it editable